# WatchOS ScrollReader Proxy Sluggish Scrolling

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos, scrollviewreader

For WatchOS, I'm trying to build a ScrollView that auto scrolls to the last item added to a list.  This all works fine, however once the ScrollView is full of content, the `scrollTo` func becomes very sluggish and slow.  Setting the animation duration for `withAnimation` has no effect at this point.  Any ideas why the animation begins to slow down?  Thanks in advance.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [Date] = []
    
    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss:SSS"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(Self.dateFormatter.string(from: item))
                                .font(.system(size: 16.0))
                                .padding()
                                .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                                        .fill(Color.blue)
                                )
                                .id(item)
                        }
                    }
                    .onReceive(items.publisher) { date in
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)) {
                            scrollProxy.scrollTo(date, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button("Add Item", action: { items.append(Date()) })
        }
    }
}
```